# Need proper way to add variable to URLWithString

Tags: variables, nsuserdefaults, nsurl

I have a variable called "sellPhone". I want to add it into the URLWithString. What is proper code to do so?

```
- (IBAction)buttonCall:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *sellPhone = [defaults objectForKey:@"sellPhone"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:%",sellPhone]]; //something like this!!!
```

What is correct way? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",sellPhone]]

To return back to app after call ended:
UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURL *telURL =  [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",sellPhone];
[callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];

Comment: You always help me! thanks! It worked! However, the only problem is that it tries to dial some random 4 digit number. I know my number is stored in NSDefaults correct because i see it on other screens. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: After reading sellPhone put a NSLog("%@",sellPhone); to ensure it has the number you want. It should work just fine.

Comment: Operator error!!! Was reading wrong nsdefault string! haha. You rock once again!!! I like seeing it in the log too. Thank you again! I will owe you a beer one day. hahahaha.

Comment: hahaha i'm glad to help! :) It's a good debugging method to add NSLog() and breakpoints to check your code. It helps a lot!!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to also know how to get it to return to my app after call completes do you? :)

Comment: I edited the first answer..try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: - (IBAction)buttonCall:(id)sender {
    
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *phone = [defaults objectForKey:@"phone"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone]]];
    NSLog(@"%@",phone);
    
    UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init]; NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone]];
                                                                        [callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];

}

Comment: Remove the entire [[UIApplication......] command. Also, if you run the app in simulator it won't work as simulator can not make calls.

Comment: Ok, so i'm running on my iPhone...but its not launching the phone app now. I get the right number in my NSLog but it won't make the call.

Comment: Here's what i got: - (IBAction)buttonCall:(id)sender {
    
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *phone = [defaults objectForKey:@"phone"];
    
    [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone]];
    
    UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init]; NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone]];
                                                                        [callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
    NSLog(@"%@",phone);
}